# How to select load sensor for specific application

Tags: load-cell

I have a project based on weighting scale. On the internet I have seen multiple types of load cells such as shear beam, single beam, s-type, planner beam load cells etc. What type of load cell is best for my application?

I want to measure weight in the range 0-300 Kg

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: yes, i have a question that which type of load cell is better to measure upto 0-300kg weight.

Comment: choose the load cell that matches how your device is designed to work - if the sensor is driven through a lever then you need to think about the reading you will get compared to the mass. BTW kg is mass, Newtons (N) is weight.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is probably your first design, I wouldn't worry about the "type" of the load cell. Just worry about the geometry, load rating, and output specs. Once you have a functional design, you may discover more specific requirements that dictate one type of load cell or another.